# symbols not showing up when debugging under clang 3.3/3.4 vs gcc 4.8

Tags: c++, clang

Situation:

I have an autotools project, written in c++11, that I can compile using either clang 3.3/3.4 or gcc 4.8.
My autotools project builds a shared library, and an executable.

If I use gcc 4.8, and debug the executable, I can add a watchpoint to inspect the value of a global variable that exists in the shared library.

When I use QT creator or CDT or other debugger, or even when I look at the output of gdb 7.6.2:  when compiled with clang, it says "no such value" in the debugging output, whereas with gcc I can inspect the values of the global variable in the debugger.

I'm sending essentially the same switches to gcc and clang, -O0 -g.  With both compilers, I can inspect and see values on the stack, but just with clang 3.3 or clang 3.4 generated output I cannot inspect global variables that exist in the shared library.  My environment is Ubuntu 12.04, with self-compiled clang and gdb.

I have confirmed that the global symbols I'm inspecting do exist in the shared library generated by either compilers.

Is there some particular compiler switch or something that I should be sending to clang in order to be able to debug the symbols in the shared library?  Or is this possibly a bug with clang?

Comment: Have you tried to list the available symbols inside GDB (I'm assuming, you should mention the debugger)? It's possible there is some name mangling going on, for example. Another thing would be to have the compiler output the target-specific assembly code and see what it's named there (in GCC it's `gcc -S`, IIRC).

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience clang 3.3 messes up debug information. Let's consider for example a simple program:

```
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::string s("foo");
  s.size();

  return 0;
}
```

Compile:

```
$ clang++ -O0 -ggdb -c t.cpp -o t.o
```

Now let's check the debug symbols:

```
$ objdump --dwarf=info t.o | grep -A2 -B1 _Rep
 <3><3c3>: Abbrev Number: 29 (DW_TAG_structure_type)
    <3c4>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x2ff): _Rep
    <3c8>   DW_AT_declaration : 1
 <3><3c8>: Abbrev Number: 28 (DW_TAG_subprogram)
```

As you can see _Rep (it's a part of std::string) is marked with the DW_AT_declaration attribute, which means _Rep is declared, but not defined. This is the reason why when debugging with gdb if you try `print s` for the program above you will see `No type named std::basic_string<char>::_Rep`.

This is how the debug information for `_Rep` really has to look like:

```
$ objdump --dwarf=info t.o | grep -P -A4 -B1 '\b_Rep\b'
 <3><119>: Abbrev Number: 16 (DW_TAG_structure_type)
    <11a>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x578): _Rep
    <11e>   DW_AT_byte_size   : 24
    <11f>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 7
    <120>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 155
 <4><121>: Abbrev Number: 11 (DW_TAG_inheritance)
```

I bet you faced this or similar situation with your clang.